# how i have custom Card with TextField i want to sum each TextField eneterd value to a single variable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

Actually I have create Sale page when i select a customer list of bill number i get and when i select any bill number the product list card shows. There is one text Field when i put value in the text field its multiply with the  net-amount . its work fine for one card product but not work properly for ,multiple card its give initial value of net-amount when **i want to put value in the 2nd text field. I just want to add net-amount  from different text.**

```
class ItemCardSaleReturn extends StatelessWidget {
Products pro;
SaleBillDetail saleBillDetail;

ItemCardSaleReturn({
  Key? key,
  required this.pro,
  required this.saleBillDetail,`enter code here`
}) : super(key: key);

List<String> item = ['Simple', 'Claim'];

String firstValue = 'Simple';

final itemType = Get.find<BillDetailController>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (context, setState) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(smallPadding),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Center(
                    child: Text(
                  pro.name.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: TextSizes.title),
                )),
                createSaleRow(
                    titleString: pro.price.toString(), realQuantity: 'Price'),
                createSaleRow(
                    titleString: pro.discount.toString(),
                    realQuantity: 'Discount'),
                createSaleRow(
                    titleString: pro.netAmount.toString(),
                    realQuantity: 'Net Amount'),
                createSaleRow(
                    titleString: pro.quantity.toString(),
                    realQuantity: 'Quantity'),
                createSaleRow(
                    titleString: pro.quantityReturned.toString(),
                    realQuantity: 'Remaining Quantity'),
                saleBillDetail.salesReturn == false
                    ? Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                              child: CustomTextFieldAlignStart(
                                  hintText: '0',
                                  textInputType: TextInputType.number,
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    itemType.resultSaleReturn.value =
                                        itemType.totalValue.value;
                                    itemType.initialValueSale.value =
                                        itemType.totalValue.value;
                                    if (val.isNotEmpty) {
                                      itemType.resultSaleReturn.value = itemType.resultSaleReturn.value * int.parse(val);

                                      print(
                                          'check Sume2  ==========> ${itemType.resultSaleReturn.value}');
                                      // setState((){});
                                    } else {
                                      // setState((){

                                      itemType.initialValueSale.value = itemType.resultSaleReturn.value;
                                      print(
                                          'check Sume1  ==========> ${itemType.initialValueSale}');
                                      // });
                                    }
                                  })),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: largePadding),
                              child: DropdownButton(
                                  value: firstValue,
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  items: item.map((String e) {
                                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                                        value: e,
                                        child: Text(
                                          e,
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black),
                                        ));
                                  }).toList(),
                                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      firstValue = newValue!;
                                    });
                                  }),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    : Container()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
}
```